# How do I check a checkbox in a listview when the value is null or not null?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I am creating a WPF `ListView` with multiple `GridViewColumn`s and would like to set a `CheckBox` `IsChecked` property to true or false based on a binding and whether or not that data value is null or not null.

I tried using a DataTrigger below to accomplish this but it doesn't seem to be working. It basically keeps everything unchecked in the `ListView`.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="W()" Width="20" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="Tell me something" >
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WebsiteJob}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Is there a way for me to handle specific columns in a `ListView` with `GridViewColumn` based on their binding? Truly in this situation I want to supply the `CheckBox` with some custom content as well as set it to IsChecked. I am pretty new to WPF so be easy.

Comment: Might be easier to use a converter instead or a data trigger.

Comment: @mattburland or even easier to handle this at the ViewModel level and return a significant property value that the UI can understand or show directly.

Comment: The converter does part of it. The ConvertBack method is having issues though. I would need to somehow store that original objects value in the check.

Comment: @HighCore I would love to see examples of what your talking about with ViewModel. I have never messed with that before.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why not have a simple getter property that would return true or false depending on some condition? You can then bind IsChecked to the value returned by this property.

Comment: @CodeWorks What do you mean? I am trying to think in that direction but the first thing that comes to mind is because I am using a Binding to load the data into the listview itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I did based on the advice in the question comments. I created an IValueConverter which stores the original object. This allows me to perform all kinds of validation on the nested object itself and then set it back when its done.

```
public class CheckboxIsCheckedValueConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object OriginalValue;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value != null) {
            OriginalValue = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if ((bool)value == true) {
            return OriginalValue;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I had to change the xaml import to the following below. Even though `x:Shared` doesn't popup in Intellisense it still does exist. This makes sure that each instance of the converter is unique and allows me to store the original value.

```
<l:CheckboxIsCheckedValueConverter x:Key="CheckboxIsCheckedValueConverter" x:Shared="False" />
```

Modified GridViewColumn

```
<GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource SmokeStyleHeaders}" Header="W()" Width="30" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Foreground="White" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding WebsiteJob, Converter={StaticResource CheckboxIsCheckedValueConverter}}" Content="{Binding WebsiteJob, Converter={StaticResource WebsiteJobValueConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```